# Apple Shortcuts SSH stop command

Tags: ios, applescript, sirishortcuts

I have raspberry pi that is controlling some LEDs strip.
I have python script that is running in loop in order to control the LEDs.

At the moment I can start script by terminal and use CTRL+C command to stop it. When script is stopped all LEDs turn off.

I made Apple Shortcut to send same SSH command to RPi to start the script. When command is send shortcut stays in "active" mode (it shows the square STOP icon), even if I stop the shortcut everthing is running okay, but I can't figure out a way to send CTRL+C command to SSH after leaving application on iOS device.

Can anyone help, give me some idea?

Kind Regards